# How to consume messages from a Pub/sub across GCP projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stream, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

Currently, I have a GCP project: **PROJECT A** where a subscription is configured to stream messages.

The challenge is to consume the messages from the subscription in **PROJECT A** using **PROJECT B** & Dataflow.

When I execute the pipeline on my local and using my personal account, the messages are being consumed successfully, but once I deploy to glcloud I'm getting PERMISION DENIED errors at the time of accessing the subscription in **PROJECT A** from **PROJECT B**

Do you know the correct permissions or steps to set in both projects to be able to consume the subscription across projects?

Thanks!

Comment: To properly replicate your use case, can you share the exact permission error message you got and also the exact gcloud command you used to deploy?

Comment: Hi Scott, this is the error:

Warning Querying the configuration of Pub/Sub subscription projects/Project-A/subscriptions/my-sub failed. Specific error: PERMISSION_DENIED: 
...
{ argument { string_val: "projects/Project-A/subscriptions/my-sub" key: "subscription_name" } argument { string_val: "User not authorized to perform this action." key: "error" } [dist_proc.dax.pubsub_resource_message_ext]: GETTING_PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_FAILED }']

Comment: The execution is made by gcloud builder

Comment: Have you tried adding roles/pubsub.subscriber on PROJECT A's service account in PROJECT B? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#accessing_pubsub

Comment: What @ScottB said is probably what you need. Further to what they said, Google provide guides on cross-platform pubsub like this one: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#sample_use_case_cross-project_communication

Comment: Please let me define the steps: 1. Create a service account in PROJECT A with access to the Subscription 2.Add roles to the service account from (1) in PROJECT B?

Comment: @MasterC that is correct.